# Permanently delete DIV from code content by ID on the frontend

Tags: html, jquery, frontend

I have on my site, a page with several DIV's with some content (let's say that each one is a TO DO task).

I need to view that page URL and choose which DIV I want to delete permanently (in a way that even if I refresh the page, it won't be there anymore).

Is this possible?

I have this code, but the "deleted" DIV re-apear as soon I refresh the page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
  
<html>  
<head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $("#removeDIVid1").click(function () {  
            $("#id1").remove();  
        });
  
        $("#removeDIVid2").click(function () {  
            $("#id2").remove();  
        });
          
        $("#removeDIVid3").click(function () {  
            $("#id3").remove();  
        });
    });  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>  


<div id="id1"><p>paragraph 1 <button id="removeDIVid1">Remove DIVid1</button></p></div>
<div id="id2"><p>paragraph 2 <button id="removeDIVid2">Remove DIVid2</button></p></div>
<div id="id3"><p>paragraph 3 <button id="removeDIVid3">Remove DIVid3</button></p></div>


</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: This can be done with `localStorage` and a value condition that. For example, if the value 1 is loaded (`localStorage.getItem()`), then after building the DOM, run the `remove()` method. This is a "crutch" in my opinion, it will work.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov can you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` method just takes the object out of the DOM, and when you refresh the page, since the DOM tree is generated again, with your div elements. I think generating these tasks dynamically using jQuery will solve your problem. Let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: Hi, @notnotparas Can you please help with the code?